# Which package in Guix provides command/binary $x?

Tags: guix

Say I want to find out which package provides binary $x on my Guix system. On a Debian based system I would use the command `apt-file search $x` and on a RedHat system I would use `yum whatprovides $x`; what would be the equivalent command on Guix System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to mroh on irc://irc.freenode.net/#guix there is currently no such command. (2020-07-05)

Answer (score 1):

All binaries on GUIX are stored in `/gnu/store` and symlinked from your profile. What works for me is simply following these symlinks:

```
$ realpath $(which convert)
/gnu/store/wskkhrm3ypybf4k6c2ar7d8sgp2v3x43-imagemagick-6.9.12-4/bin/convert
```

Which means that the `convert` command is provided by the `imagemagick` package.

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't have the command yet, you just know you need it (e.g. because make told you so) and it isn't provided by a package called itself.

Comment: I could swear there was a solution now via the Guix Data Service making it possible to search through pre-built packages. I just don't remember where.